# display automatic date in input

Tags: php, input, datepicker, user-input, invoice

I am making a invoices page and I want the date to appear automatically as an input as well as the date of expiration (30 days later)

is there an automatic function?

I have this:

TD

can value change to something like todaysdate??? or 30 days later??

help! :D

Comment: This question is vague and spasmodic. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DateTime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method.

```
<?php

  $date = new DateTime('2011-01-01');
  $date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Which version of PHP do you have? DateTime::Add method is available in PHP 5.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely difficult to decipher.

Perhaps you are looking for PHP's strtotime() function. For example, strtotime('today') returns a timestamp for today's date, and strtotime('next Wednesday') returns a timestamp for next Wednesday.